# Multiple inheritance in python3 with different signatures

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have three classes: `A`, `B` and `C`.

`C` inherits from `A` and `B` (in this order). The constructor signatures of `A` and `B` are different. How can I call the `__init__` methods of both parent classes?

My endeavour in code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print('Init {} with arguments {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, (a, b)))

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, q):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print('Init {} with arguments {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, (q)))

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__(1, 2)
        super(B, self).__init__(3)

c = C()
```

yields the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    c = C()
  File "test.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(A, self).__init__(1, 2)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I found [this resource](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/inheritance-python) which explains mutiple inheritance with different set of arguments, but they suggest to use `*args` and `**kwargs` to use for all argument. I consider this very ugly, since I cannot see from the constructor call in the child class what kind of parameters I pass to the parent classes.

Comment: You're using `super` wrong, that should just be `super(C, self).__init__` in `C.__init__`. As you have different signatures, you have no choice but to handle arbitrary `*args, **kwargs` if you want to use `super`.

Comment: `super()` is for when you are using mixins. Don't use it when you have different signatures.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Do **not** use `super(baseclass, ...)` unless you know what you are doing. The first argument to `super()` tells it what class to **skip** when looking for the next method to use. E.g. `super(A, ...)` will look at the MRO, find `A`, then start looking for `__init__` on the **next** baseclass, **not** `A` itself. For `C`, the MRO is `(C, A, B, object)`, so `super(A, self).__init__` will find `B.__init__`.

For these cases, you don't want to use cooperative inheritance but directly reference `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` instead. `super()` should only be used if the methods you are calling have the *same signature* or will swallow unsupported arguments with `*args` and `**vargs`. In that case just the one `super(C, self).__init__()` call would be needed and the next class in the MRO order would take care of chaining on the call.

Putting it differently: when you use `super()`, you can not know what class will be next in the MRO, so that class better support the arguments you pass to it. If that isn't the case, do *not* use `super()`.

Calling the base `__init__` methods directly:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print('Init {} with arguments {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, (a, b)))

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, q):
        print('Init {} with arguments {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, (q)))

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        # Unbound functions, so pass in self explicitly
        A.__init__(self, 1, 2)
        B.__init__(self, 3)
```

Using cooperative `super()`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Init {} with arguments {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, (a, b)))

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, q=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Init {} with arguments {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, (q)))

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(a=1, b=2, q=3)
```

Comment: @NikolaiTschacher: how else would you ask for the method on the *next* class in the MRO, without knowing what that class might be? You always know the **current** class you are defining the method for, however.

Comment: I thought that super() without any class as argument just walks up MRO as it was defined in the subclass class statement: MRO for class A(B, C, D) is A,B,C,D. Furthermore I assumed that calling super(A, self) with an explicit Argument just visits the class that was provided in the super call and that the caller needs to check that any other parent classes are constructed correctly. So super(A, self) in my mindset would only ever visit class A, nothing else. I practically thought that A.__init__(self) is equivalent to  super(A, self). Additionally I haven't fully understood super() I guess...

Comment: @NikolaiTschacher: It helps if you understood what problem `super()` is trying to solve: calling the *next* method in the order in a complex hierarchy with diamond pattern inheritance (a base class used by multiple subclasses). In such cases using explicit `BaseClass.__init__` calls becomes error prone and you end up with multiple calls to `SharedBaseClass.__init__`. By using the MRO instead you have a guaranteed order, but that order is *dynamic* based on inheritance. This means you should not care about what the next class is, just make sure that any of them can accept that call.

Comment: I find it worth noting that for cooperative inheritance superclasses *need* to call `super().__init__()` within their `__init__()`. Without, the MRO chain breaks and the `__init__()` methods of following classes in the chain are not called.