# Multiple inheritance and super()

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, superclass

I'm a beginner and this doubt caught me...

I have the class `ProfessorAuxiliar` which inherits the attributes of the classes `Professor` and `Aluno`.
But when using `super()` it returns `TypeError: __init __ () takes 7 positional arguments but 10 were given`.

```
...

class Aluno(Pessoa):

    def __init__(self, nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo, matricula, semestre, curso):
        super().__init__(nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo)
        self.__matricula = matricula
        self.__semestre = semestre
        self.__curso = curso


class Professor(Pessoa):

    __lista_de_indicacoes = []

    def __init__(self, nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo, materia):
        super().__init__(nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo)
        self.__materia = materia

class ProfessorAuxiliar(Professor, Aluno):

    def __init__(self, nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo, materia, matricula, semestre, curso):
        super().__init__(nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo, materia, matricula, semestre, curso)

...
```

How can I make the `ProfessorAuxiliar` class inherit all the attributes of the other 2?

Comment: For further explanation, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927571/multiple-inheritance-in-python3-with-different-signatures) thread is very useful.

Comment: You seem to rely on the constructor for **every** setting. For semester and course this does not appear convincing. As soon as you concentrate person data on a single parent class, you will no longer have collisions (i.e. have to pass the same parameters to different parent classes) and might even no longer need multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `super`, try using `parent_classname.__init__()` for each of the inherited classes & pass those args accordingly to those parent classes' constructors.
**EDIT:** In the `ProfessorAuxiliar` class

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I think is the correct way.

```
class ProfessorAuxiliar(Professor, Aluno): 

    def __init__(self, nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo, materia, matricula, semestre, curso):
        Professor.__init__(self,self, nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo, matricula, semestre, curso)
        Aluno.__init__(self,nome, sobrenome, cpf, data, sexo)
```